# Is it ok to disable Hermes to update an app that is already published on Play Store?

Tags: android, react-native

We have an app that is publish on Play Store. Using React Native version 0.68.5. Some users are experiencing crashes that we suspect are caused by Hermes Engine. Is it ok to disable Hermes and upload a new update or will it cause more issues if the app was published with Hermes enabled ?

App does not crash on debug so we were unable to determine the cause of the crashes.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by: "Is it OK?' Are you concerned with performance regressions, or are you concerned that it would cause more crashes? Also, what makes you think that Hermes is causing these crashes?

Comment: Our concern is whether it will causes crashes. The reason why we suspect it's Hermes because one of the issues logs this: "couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes.so caused by: dlopen failed: library "/vendor/lib64/libhermes.so" not found result: 0"

Comment: You should consider upgrading to version 0.71. or above It seems that this is a known bug that was fixed starting from that version (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35374).

As far as your question is concerned, thinking from first principles only, I'd say it shouldn't cause any crashes. You can always enable an Alpha/Beta track to test it out before rolling it out to actual users though. Also, you can also just test your release build before releasing it.